# how to create a link to next page (currentpage+1)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 30 pages. sort by numbers  ?page1 ?page2 ?page3......?page30

Assume Now, I stay on page=1
http://localhost/flowplayer/manga/manga_demo2.php?page=1

and If I want to add a button that link to next page (current page+1) How should I do?

This is my try but not work.

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] + 1;?>';" value="Next">
```

Comment: You can use $_GET['page'] to get the current value of the page number and plus it with one... Be sure to sanitize the string using either strip tags or htmlspecialchars. Google sanitizing GET php

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] + 1;?>';" value="Next">
instead of this you can do :
<input type="button" onClick="nextPage()"/>
function nextPage()
{
   var urlName=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   var newUrlName=substr(urlName,0,urlName.length-6)."page=";
   var appendedValue=$_GET["page"]+1;
   location.href=newUrlName.appendedValue;

}
```

Comment: I hope you realise that you can't just call PHP variables inside Javascript functions like that..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this would do just fine. Explanation in comments:

```
<?php

/* Get the full URL */
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

/* Get the page number */
$page = substr($url, -1);

/* Check if it's really a number for security */
if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $page)){
    die("Invalid page number given!");
}

/* Remove the page number from the URL */
$url = rtrim($url, $page);

/* Count the page up with +1 */
$page++;

/* Generage the new url */
$newurl = $url . $page;

?>

<!-- Put it inside your button element -->

<input type="button" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $newurl; ?>';" value="Next">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can really do it without any php code

```
<button id="b">click</button>
<script>
var pageStr=location.href.split("page=")[1];
var pageId=Number(pageStr);
b.onclick=function(){
    location.href="http://localhost/flowplayer/manga/manga_demo2.php?page="+ ++pageId;
}
</script>
```